# How to store binary data referenced by 3D coordinates (xyz)?

Tags: 3d, software-recommendations, data-storage

I would like to store huge amounts of voxels (3D cubes with color and some other values) in a gis database.

Does someone can recommend a database (indexing) system, where I can store binary data (a sparse voxel octree) and find it by a 3D coordinate query?

Comment: PostGis can store 3d data, but it is not fully developed yet (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/3/36/Postgis_3d_pgday2013_hm.pdf) and http://postgis3d.blogspot.com.au/ (geometry type POLYHEDRALSURFACE) true 3d is still emerging technology.

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to store polyons.Only voxels.

Comment: You should almost certainly look at Rasdaman, it can store multiple-dimensional data not just 3D

Answer (score -1):

Currently I decided to have a closer look on [Geode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index). It seems to enable flexible extensions to many types of data and is still quite fast, as some people say.... :)